# login/logout with same LoginId

Tags: java, session

I have developed a web app with `Struts` and `Hibernet`.

Now i want to make login mechanism like as :

Suppose user A login with login id A ==> it will allow to login

now at same time User B login with login id A ==> it also allow to login but previous login  User A will be logout and latest login user B is active....

In simple word LOGIN WITH SAME LOGINID WILL ALLOW BUT LATEST ONE IS ACTIVE AND PREVIOUS ONE IS LOGOUT AUTOMATICALLY.....??

i have manage sessionID and loginID with hashtable ...

I dont want to use database mechanism ....

I hope u got my question .. PLs help me ...!!!
Thanks in advance....

Comment: possible duplicate of [multilogin with same user id....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458679/multilogin-with-same-user-id)

Comment: @org. i knw that this is duplicate but didnt got that answer... if u have any solution plz.. tell me .. plz....

Comment: I have already provided there which has been accepted by you :)

Comment: of course , i have accepted your ans .. but not able to do with that one .. i have managed all this in loginAction.java action class.. and i am not able to go with your solution DEAR ......

Answer (score 0):

I assume its Single Sign On, similar to the login process we find in Yahoo Messenger.

Following steps might help you in developing the same

- Implement no-cache policy [ Setting no-cache headers to response ]
- Store user_id to session id, or last_login time etc in database
- Instead of holding user login information in session , storing it in cache will be helpful
- If new user logs in with same id, just nullify previous session in the cache, this makes other user who has already logged in for forceful logout [ Assuming you check user login status for every request]